# getting anchor elements from a web page

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I want to access elements from a web page.

for example I am using jquery : 
`$("#links").load('http://www.youtube.com a');`  to bring all the links from youtube page to my local page.

But I am not able to do it, getting an error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=&go=Go. Origin "my
>   local host " is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

When i try to do this with another local page I am getting it.

any help? 
Hope i explained my question properly.

Comment: AJAX calls do not work across domains. You can only use $.load() locally.

Comment: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Hi, thanks there. Can u please suggest how can I achieve it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin is the browser preventing the page from loading content from another site. This is a security feature by design ([HTTP Access Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

The only / best way to do it is via a server side page (PHP etc) passing the page to your website.